# File is not deleted when I send it via Java Sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I have developed an application that sends file to remote user using Java Sockets. File is transmitted in bytes. Error is when I delete the file, it is deleted but next day when I turn on my Laptop same file name is there with 0 byte file size. Same is repeated for 2 more days then I need to delete it via command prompt.

Comment: please share your code what you have done till now

Comment: Which file? OS? Code? Purpose of the whole thing?

Comment: do you call `close` after delete?

Comment: Is that file maybe created by some other application?

Comment: Here's a random question: are you using RandomAccessFile? Either way: show some code

Comment: Guys I don't know what was the problem but now the file is not coming back... And I checked it by restarting it for 3-4 times.... Thank you all of you....:)